# A library for cross-platform (C++/Android) lossless/low noise video compression/decompression

Tags: android, c++, cross-platform, video-streaming, lossless-compression

I have a need to compress a video stream to transfer it from a C++ library to a Java platform (Android) by network and decompress it there.
The requirements are as follows:

- The library must be available both for Android platform and C++ (or, 2 separate libraries using a common format)
- Compression must be lossless OR lossy with minimal artifacts
- Library(-ies) must be free/opensource

The specifics of the task are that the video stream will be an aircraft MFD type, so there will be large number of pixels which will stay same across multiple frames. This should help much in the compression.

Is there any "easy path" for the above?

Comment: Almost all video codecs are designed to be lossy. Are you sure that stream from MFD can't be compressed with some errors in minor bits?

Comment: A compression algorithm with low artifact level would be just fine too... I just felt lossless would be more of a good fit here. Are there any low-artifact lossy ones meeting other criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search from [open source video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_codecs). Seems that two are listed lossless there. How useful these are on Android or how portable is hard to tell. I don't think there are any easier paths.

Comment: And actually Lagarith is listed to be a fork from Huffyuv. I can also remember MSU Lossless codec: http://www.compression.ru/video/ls-codec/index_en.html - but it can't be used commercially. Hmm.. This list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Lossless_compression give some more variants.

Comment: The whole thing is noncommercial, so I'll choose between Lagarith and MSU. Thank you!